# Losing theme customization when switching from a theme to a child

Tags: themes

I followed the practice of creating a sub-theme (child theme) but I discovered that I lost some configuration I made:

- main custom header lost, but it remained for pages where it was customized, I had to upload it again.
- menu customization: primary navigation menu assignment was lost, but the menus did not so it was easy to reassign it.

**Are any other side effects like the one above?**

Are these **bugs or expected behavior**?

Details:

- I added a new directory in themes, created style.css with [requested header](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)
- Activated the new theme in WordPress (running in multi-site mode)
- Observed the issues above

Comment: *@Sorin* Please list out the steps you took while you did this.  There might be a step you've missed, or we might be able to better identify how to improve the "practice" you've been following.

Comment: Thanks, I added the steps, not so many. BTW, be sure you customize the header image before adding the theme.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about "lost" header. Was it part of markup? CSS background? Custom background?

Losing menu assignments is normal behavior.

- Child theme is **not same theme as parent**
- It is completely **separate theme, that uses parent as fall-back**

Child theme is loaded and processed before parent theme (yeah, seems a little backwards). Don't expect it to act simply as parent theme with some changes. It seems like that, but not quite that internally.

Comment: I didn't customize anything on disk, I just used the admin interface to upload a new header. So regarding header, is a bug?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't used custom header functionality so far. No idea about specifics. Basically if it set for a theme, than changing theme reseting it is normal. If it is set for a blog - theme change should not affect it.